# Migration application c# from Core5 to Core 6: Error No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Claim'

Tags: c#, migration

I have this weird problem.

I migrated my web-project from Core 5.0 to Core 6.0 and I got an error when communicating with Database. EF migration is not working either.

> No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Claim'. The
> following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to
> properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'reader' in
> 'Claim(BinaryReader reader)';

Not sure what the problem might be. The settings and code remained the same as in Core5, where it all worked.

DbContext is the default
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext

***Post Edit***

I edited program.cs according to the instructions

```
 var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
 var startup = new SharedWebApplication.Startup(builder.Configuration);
 startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services);
 var app = builder.Build();
 startup.Configure(app, app.Environment);
 app.Run();
```

The startup.cs remained the same

DB settings

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
      options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
      sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(60)));
```

Identity settings

```
 services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
      .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
      .AddDefaultUI()
      .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

The problem is with communication with the database. Context is somehow mis-evaluating the 'Claim' inherited from IdentityDbContext

Thank you

### The error is somewhere in the NUGET Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

When I use version 5.17 so everything is OK, but if I update to version 6.0+ so the error occurs

> No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Claim'.

Therefore, Nugety must have the maximum version 5.17

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

Comment: There are a few changes with hosting moving from 5 to 6. [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio). You'll have to provide information on how you've configured you app if you need more assistance.

Comment: Does your claim class have a default constructor?

Comment: I don't overlay classes I use standard classes.